# Layer button xtypes on top of img xtypes in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to put 3 buttons on top of an `xtype:'img'`, but I'm getting nowhere and can't find much online about it.

How does this work?

EDIT:

i have an image and when you tap it i want it to display the same image but now there are 3 options you can choose from view download share i want the buttons to look like they pop up over the image

```
Ext.define('Crystal.view.apphb',{
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'apphb',
    id:'panel',
requires: [

   'Ext.TitleBar',

],
 config:{
 layout: {
    type: 'card',
    animation: {
        type: 'fade'},
 },

items:[{

    xtype:'img',
 src:'resources/img/apphb.png',

listeners: {
            tap: function() {
                Ext.getCmp('panel').setActiveItem(1);
            },
            },

},

{





    xtype:'img',
 src:'resources/img/1.png',

 listeners: {
  tap: function() {
                Ext.getCmp('panel').setActiveItem(-1);
                }
                },






    }
]
```

}

});

Comment: so what exactly are you trying to do? I don't think you can do that from my understanding... I could be wrong. More code would probably be helpful

Comment: basically I want 3 buttons to show or float on top of an image almost like a xtype messagebox does except with out the black background

Comment: is that more helpful?

Comment: yeah but I don't think you can place button on top of `xtype:img`. Maybe if you have some more code I could see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok its updated with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from your question is simple. You want to show certain buttons in a pop up on tap of image. So you use [overlays](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/overlays) and put buttons inside it.

A working fiddle with demo is [here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#YoKqQ). You can display anything in you want in this pop up. 
The method [.showBy()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-showBy) let you place pop up relative to certain element passed as parameter. Here's the code,

```
launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'image',
                    src: 'http://www.sencha.com/assets/images/sencha-avatar-64x64.png',
                    height: 64,
                    width: 64,
                    listeners:{
                        tap:function( img,e,opts ){
                           var overlay = Ext.Viewport.add({
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            left: 0,
                            top: 0,                       
                            modal: true,
                            hideOnMaskTap: true,
                            hidden: true,
                            width:160,
                            height:90,                          
                               items:[
                                   {
                                       xtype:'button',
                                       text:'Download'
                                   }
                               ],
                            styleHtmlContent: true,
                            scrollable: true
                        });             
                    overlay.showBy(img);
                       }
                    }
                }
                ]
        });
    }
```

Comment: the way SO works, if anyone give downvote it's his responsibility to give reason behind that. that will definitely point out mistakes answerer has done.

Comment: What if I want to download/save the image when I click the Download button? Can I add this functionality if yes how ? Please refer my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756690/how-save-image-to-phone-memory-say-sd-card-or-local-hard-drive-when-a-image-tap) ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what about using img as the background for the container?

```
    xtype: 'container',
                style: 'background: url(http://wallpapers.free-review.net/wallpapers/36/New_Batman_movie.jpg) no-repeat;',
                layout: {
                    align: 'stretch',
                    type: 'vbox'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex: 1
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        height: 100,
                        defaults: {
                            margin: 5,
                            height: 80,
                            width: 100
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                text: 'Like'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                text: 'Tweet'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```